# Extended Inline Assembly GCC- bad register name and junk 'done' after expression error when compiling

Tags: c, gcc, assembly, x86

I'm writing a program using assembly code to write a program that calculate one of the quadratic equation roots. I've written all of my code, but I have the following error:

```
main.c:37: Error: bad register name `%qword'
main.c:39: Error: junk `done' after expression
```

How do I correct those error, please?

My codes is:

```
// function for checking that assembly code is computing the correct result
double quadraticRootC(double a, double b, double c)
{
    return (-b + sqrt(b * b - 4 * a * c)) / (2 * a);
}

double quadraticRoot(double a, double b, double c)
{
    double root;

    asm(
        "fld        %1              \n"
        "fadd       %%ST            \n"
        "fld        %1              \n"
        "fld        %3              \n"
        "fmulp      %%ST(1)         \n"
        "fadd       %%ST            \n"
        "fadd       %%ST            \n"
        "fchs                       \n"
        "fld        %2              \n"
        "fld        %2              \n"
        "fmulp      %%ST(1)         \n"
        "faddp      %%ST(1)         \n"
        "ftst                       \n"
        "fstsw      %%1X            \n"
        "sahf                       \n"
        "fsqrt                      \n"
        "fld        %2              \n"
        "fchs                       \n"
        "fdivp      %%ST(1)         \n"
        "mov        %0, %%eax    \n"
        "fstp       %%qword, %%eax  \n"
        "mov        $1, %%eax       \n"
        "jmp        short done      \n"
        "done:                      \n"
        :"=g"(root)
        :"g"(a), "g"(b), "g"(c)
        :"eax"
        );
    return(root);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    double  a, b, c;
    double  root, rootC;

    if (argc != 4) {
        printf("need 3 arguments: a, b, c\n");
        return -1;
    }
    a = atof(argv[1]);
    b = atof(argv[2]);
    c = atof(argv[3]);
    root = quadraticRoot(a, b, c);
    rootC = quadraticRootC(a, b, c);

    printf("quadraticRoot(%.3f, %.3f, %.3f) = %.3f, %.3f\n", a, b, c, root, rootC);

    return 0;
}
```

The line where the error occurs:

```
"mov        %0, %%eax    \n"
"fstp       %%qword, %%eax  \n"
"mov        $1, %%eax       \n"
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I would argue that the problem is that you're using inline assembly to begin with. First make a proper C solution, build using optimizations, measure and profile to see if the code is actually a bottleneck, and first then try to look at the generated code to see if you could possibly hand-optimize it better.

Comment: What compile options are you using?

Comment: `fstp qword,eax` doesn't look like a valid asm instruction.  What exactly did you expect this statement to do?  I am also curious about `mov %0, %%eax`.  You are reading from (root)?

Comment: You do many things that don't make sense, and ultimately the entire idea of doing this in assembly is dubious, and I say that not because I don't like assembly (I do) but because this is the kind of code that gets compiled very well (but you will need the appropriate compiler options to ensure the result of the square root is not checked).

Comment: There's a few things wrong here. As an example - how do you know that `%eax` isn't chosen to be one of the input or output registers, in which case the clobber is invalid? You would probably be better off investing your time in learning how to use SSE scalar operations, but some things are just interesting in and of themselves. Have a look at a much better [inline assembly tutorial](http://locklessinc.com/articles/gcc_asm/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apart from the errors you listed, there were some other issues. The main one being that the default operand size for `fld` is single precision, while you have doubles. So you need to explicitly use `fldl`. Second, if you ever find yourself using `g` constraint, think twice, because chances are you are doing something wrong. In this case, the input operands should be memory references (`m` constraint), and the output should be left in the FPU stack (`t` constraint). I have removed the unused code dealing with the status word for now, I suppose that is a placeholder to detect taking the square root of a negative number.

You should always comment your code, but especially if you ask others for help. Since you haven't done that, I have no idea what you wanted to do with `eax` at the end. I removed that too.

Here is a [working version](http://ideone.com/JeqM4t):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

// function for checking that assembly code is computing the correct result
double quadraticRootC(double a, double b, double c)
{
    return (-b + sqrt(b * b - 4 * a * c)) / (2 * a);
}

double quadraticRoot(double a, double b, double c)
{
    double root;

    asm(
        "fldl       %1       # a                   \n"
        "fadd       %%ST     # 2a                  \n"
        "fldl       %1       # a 2a                \n"
        "fldl       %3       # c a 2a              \n"
        "fmulp      %%ST(1)  # ac 2a               \n"
        "fadd       %%ST     # 2ac 2a              \n"
        "fadd       %%ST     # 4ac 2a              \n"
        "fldl       %2       # b 4ac 2a            \n"
        "fldl       %2       # b b 4ac 2a          \n"
        "fmulp      %%ST(1)  # b^2 4ac 2a          \n"
        "fsubp      %%ST(1)  # b^2-4ac 2a          \n"
        "fsqrt               # sqrt(b^2-4ac) 2a    \n"
        "fldl       %2       # b sqrt(b^2-4ac) 2a  \n"
        "fchs                # -b sqrt(b^2-4ac) 2a \n"
        "faddp      %%ST(1)  # -b+sqrt(b^2-4ac) 2a \n"
        "fdivp      %%ST(1)  # -b+sqrt(b^2-4ac)/2a \n"
        :"=t"(root)
        :"m"(a), "m"(b), "m"(c)
        );
    return(root);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    double  a, b, c;
    double  root, rootC;

    if (argc != 4) {
        printf("need 3 arguments: a, b, c\n");
        return -1;
    }
    a = atof(argv[1]);
    b = atof(argv[2]);
    c = atof(argv[3]);
    root = quadraticRoot(a, b, c);
    rootC = quadraticRootC(a, b, c);

    printf("quadraticRoot(%.3f, %.3f, %.3f) = %.3f, %.3f\n", a, b, c, root, rootC);

    return 0;
}
```